Well I am trying to build a webapp using flutter and serverpod . but it throws me error of return imagecodecurl
I am using flutter and serverpod to build a webapp . And it has lot of images in it's ui .
Everytime i run it throws me like error like this:
C:/Users/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cached_network_image_web-1.2.0/lib/cached_network_image_web.dart:159:12: Error: The     
method 'createImageCodecFromUrl' isn't defined for the class 'ImageLoader'.
 - 'ImageLoader' is from 'package:cached_network_image_web/cached_network_image_web.dart'
 ('/C:/Users/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/cached_network_image_web-1.2.0/lib/cached_network_image_web.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'createImageCodecFromUrl'.
    return createImageCodecFromUrl(

well flutter doctor works fine:
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.9, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.3527], locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 3.13.9 on channel stable at C:\Users\Documents\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision d211f42860 (7 months ago), 2023-10-25 13:42:25 -0700
    • Engine revision 0545f8705d
    • Dart version 3.1.5
    • DevTools version 2.25.0

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+7-b1504.28-7817840)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.4.3)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.4.33205.214
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.22000.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Users\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\AndroidStudio\ch-0\221.6008.13.2211.9619390
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-9505619)

[√] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+0-b2043.56-10550314)

[√] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • android-studio-dir = C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+7-b1504.28-7817840)

[√] VS Code (version 1.89.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.88.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.3527]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 125.0.6422.60
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 124.0.2478.67

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!

I'm using image.network() to show the from the image the internet from url . But it gives me error
Can anyone explain this and also how to resolve this issue??

There is an open issue in this plugin
so stick to this version until it is fixed.

cached_network_image: 3.3.0


But it shows me same error ..

Finally it works , but it requires also to change to cached_network_image_web: ^1.1.0 and cached_network_image_platform_interface: ^3.0.0.  Thanks..
